# Как в java получить все числа месяца?

Tags: java, дата

Всем доброго времени суток! Например, у меня на входе есть String date = "05.2018" (май 2018). Затем я преобразую это все в тип Date. Как мне получить на выходе вот это - 
01.05.2018
02.05.2018
...
31.05.2018 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного переписал код из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35849118/5909792).

Тут используется [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) и [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) из java 8:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 1);
do {
    System.out.println(ld.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")));
    ld = ld.plusDays(1);

} while (ld.getDayOfMonth() > 1);  // arive at 1st of next month
```

В консоли:

```
01.05.2018
02.05.2018
03.05.2018
04.05.2018
...
30.05.2018
31.05.2018
```

---

**PS.**

Строку с датой можно распарсить:

```
String date = "05.2018";
String[] parts = date.split("\\.");
int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
int month = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int day = 1;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
...
```

**PPS.**

Двойные слеши нужны в `date.split("\\.");` для экранирования `.`, т.к. в `split` не просто строка-разделитель указывается, а регулярное выражение. Точка `.` в регулярках является метасимволом, поэтому и нужно экранирование -- чтобы символ считался как есть

Comment: Если нужно решение и для более ранних версий java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35849364/5909792

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Прибавлять по одному дню:

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays();
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>(days);  // Список дат.
for (int i=0; i < days; i++) {
    LocalDate d = startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), i);
    dates.add(d);
}
```

Comment: а что за класс Days в java, гугли не нашел...

Comment: @Жаважуниор, походу из: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Days.html

Answer (score 0):

Просто ради тренировки, решение с использованием потоков:

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 1);
Stream.iterate(ld.withDayOfMonth(1), t -> t.plusDays(1)).limit(ld.lengthOfMonth()).peek(System.out::println).count();
```